# git push/fetch - what commits will be synchronized?

Tags: git

I have the following structure of commits in my local git repository:

```
                              branch-feature1
                                 |
               |-> commit3 -> commit4
               |
 commit1 -> commit2
               |
               |-> commit5 -> commit6
                                 |
                              branch-feature2
```

1) Am I right to think that when I run `git push remote branch-feature1`, only commits from commit1 through commit4 will be synchronized to remote repository, while commmit5 and commit6 will be left out?

2) Now suppose I have the same commits structure presented above in remote repository. Am I right to think that when I run 'git fetch remote' I will have all 6 commits synchronized to my local repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Your assumptions are correct.  commit5 and 6 would be left out with `git push remote branch-feature1`.  You could push all tracking branches with `git push remote :` (which used to be the default), but that's dangerous and I'll explain why.

Imagine this: you're happily chugging away on your branch while several new commits show up on master.  You decide that you need to amend a commit and that will require you to force the push with `git push -f`.  Now, it used to be that git would push all tracking branches by default, so this would mean that if you did not fast-forward any other branches with the latest updates, then you'd end up rolling back master to whatever version your local master was at!  This is clearly a bad situation, so the default changed to make it less dangerous for folks.

It is possible to set a different policy than the default.  Look at `push.default` in the [`git-config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) man page.  Also, push uses the fetch refspec by default, but you could chose a different one.  See `remote.<name>.push` in the same man page.

2) Yes, all of the commits would be brought back locally with `branch-feature1` becoming `refs/remotes/<remote>/branch-feature1` and the same for `branch-feature2`.  That is, as long as you didn't change the refspec being used for fetching, or set a push refspec.  It is occasionally useful to change things from the defaults.  For instance, when working on an open source project, I typically have my fork living at `origin`, and the real project at `upstream`.  I often only take the `master` branch from the `upstream` with:

```
[remote.upstream.fetch]
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/upstream/master
```